# Can more than one coordinating conjunction be used in a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

Can more than one coordinating conjunction (and, but, or, etc.) be used in a sentence?

**For example:**
"It was never my intention to become wealthy, but opportunities seemed to just happen, and I was not about to refuse them."

Comment: This is a strange question. Not only is this a perfectly natural construction, but you will in fact be hard pressed to name *one* writer who has never used it.

Comment: Great. I somehow felt this wasn't so, and I have been avoiding doing this for quite some time.

Comment: I save money, for I need a horse, or I could buy new tack. I send a letter, so to greet a friend and tell them about a show. My horse is black, but has no grace nor beauty. I like competing, for I enjoy the work and challenge it offers. I like riding horses so I practice, for I want to win. My trainer makes me work hard, yet let's me have fun, so I keep riding. My sister has three eyes and ears, yet cannot see, nor hear. My friend likes dogs and is learning to like cats, but doesn't like bunnies and hamsters. My mom is my trainer, and supports my riding, but makes me do homework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use multiple conjunctions in a sentence, and although it may produce something which seems a bit verbose, there are appropriate uses for it, and in literature in particular, it's commonly used to create a sense of continuity throughout a scene by forcing the reader to take in the entire paragraph without stopping, and Ernest Hemingway was famous for doing precisely that!

> I wondered if there was anything else I might pray for, and I thought I would like to have some money, so I prayed that I would make a lot of money, and then I started to think how I would make it, and thinking of making money reminded me of the count, and I started wondering about where he was, and regretting I hadn’t seen him since that night in Montmartre, and about something funny Brett told me about him, and as all the time I was kneeling with my forehead on the wood in front of me, and was thinking of myself as praying, I was a little ashamed, and regretted that I was such a rotten Catholic, but realized there was nothing I could do about it, at least for a while, and maybe never, but that anyway it was a grand religion, and I only wished I felt religious and maybe I would the next time; and then I was out in the hot sun on the steps of the cathedral, and the forefingers and the thumb of my right hand were still damp, and I felt them dry in the sun.
>
> - Ernest Hemingway, The Sun Also Rises

<sub>*Admittedly, my crude attempt was not nearly as good as Hemingway's.*</sub>

This is a literary technique. I definitely wouldn't advise it for technical writing or any formal communication. It makes the reader work a lot harder to read your sentences than would otherwise be necessary.

Comment: Excellent. I'd read this book some time ago, but I somehow hadn't noticed this. Thanks!